# .net drawlines with pens(different colors) in a loop

Tags: .net, c++-cli, pen

I want to draw lines ( about 100 ) with different colors. The lines will draw in a loop and get random colors. Here is my code:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 100 < i++ )
{
srand( time(NULL) );
int index = rand() % 99;
Pen^  my_pen = gcnew Pen((Color)CustomColorTables[index]);
g->drawLine(my_pen,startPointAray[i],stopPointArray[i]);
}
```

But it draws all lines with the same color???

Note: I checked the random values, there is no problem about generating random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the line:

```
srand( time(NULL) );
```

**BEFORE** entering the for loop.
In your case you are resetting each time the pseudo random sequence and you probably obtain a wrong sequence. 
Then use:

```
int index = (100*rand()) % 99;
```

because rand() by itself returns a number from 0 to 1 and you will always receive 99 as a % result.

Comment: @user983924 even by multiplying rand()*100 before ?

Comment: I replaced the srand function before the loop and the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: No, `rand()` returns an integer in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX`.  And even if it did return a number from 0 to 1, you wouldn't get 99 from the modulo operation.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace:

```
CustomColorTables[index];
```

with:

```
CustomColorTables[i];
```

if it works better than before as I believe, the issue is in the way you generate and use the random value index.

Comment: It draws the same, I think the problem is about the pen.

Comment: how many colors and with which value do you have in the CustomColorTables variable?

Comment: 100 colors and I cretaed the color table.